# Google Webmaster Indexed page falling down

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

Ten days before i checked my google webmaster tool and saw there was around 2000+ Total numbed of indexed page.

Since last two crawl it is falling below first 1400 then 900 why ?
I checked there are no `Removed` or `Blocked by robots` urls in `Advance Option`

and also no message or warning

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is if your pages are throwing 404, then google might drop them from index. Did you check 404s in crawl stats?

Comment: yah it is showing 404 for many pages but those are not the real urls mean its showing 404 for those urls that i have stored in javascript variable or urls that i am using in my scripts for some purpose.

Comment: If there were already existing 404s and no new ones, check to see if there were any changes to your canonical url creation. Google will drop indexes if different pages point to same canonical.

Comment: in most page i had something like `<link rel="canonical"` i guess it was cos of that ?

Comment: Were they all pointing to same link? If so, i guess that's the reason for them. Canonical are meant for a different reason. If that's the reason for the issue, i am glad i was of help. Please make sure to accept it as an answer for your question.

Comment: In every page i had `<link rel="canonical" url='url of the current page'` i dont know if that was the reason, i have removed all thos cannonical from page let see now when google index next time